# jQuery ajax datatable showing old data for some seconds for some moment?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using [jQuery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net) to show data from the database. I am using ajax to get the data. So the situation is like that I have bootstrap tabs. So when user will click on any tabs it will show the data corresponding to the tab. So my code for jQuery is like this

```
$('a.communication-data[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#get_communication').dataTable().fnDestroy();    
    var proj_id = $('input#user_project_id').val();
    var communicationTable = $('#get_communication').dataTable();
    $('#get_communication').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength" : trans.show_rows,
        "ajax": ajaxUrl+"?action=get_communication_history&proj_id="+proj_id,
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search.."
        }       
    });
});
```

Here the datatable showing the old data for some seconds and after that it is showing the actual data for the first time. When user again check the tab without page reload then it shows the correct data.
So can someone tell me why this issue is happening? How to resolve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: what is the content of the datatable before the ajax call

Comment: Maybe your request has not returned from server and while request is processed you still see old data?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky   There is no set content before ajax call.

Comment: @Justinas so can you tell me how to clear the old data as soon as I click on the tab button?

Comment: It is showing you what is in "local storage" from previous visit... Browsers can load a local copy (copy of the web from previous visit) to look faster and then they check if there are changes between the server and the loaded copy, if so, it updates, you shouldn't be able to notice it, so I guess there is something else... I had a similar problem because I use GET instead of POST to request data...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I have checked the local storage of browser but there is no data at all. Can you tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @NewUser I change all my GET calls for POST calls, because if GET find data on local storage, it will use it... But I wasn't using a plugin, I coded all ajax calls and had "full control" over them, no layers attached... The DataTables plugin allow you to specify [deferRender](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender) so it only render the table only when needed, it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the documentation and got some methods for that like `fnDrawCallback` and `fnPreDrawCallback` . Also got one [example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6027/customizing-the-processing-message) which really helped me.

So finally my code is like this

```
$('a.communication-data[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#get_communication_history').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var proj_id = $('input#user_project_id').val();
    $('#get_communication_history').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "fnPreDrawCallback": function() { 
            showMessage();
        return true;
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        hideOverlay();
        },              
        "serverSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength" : trans.show_rows,
        "ajax": ajaxUrl+"?action=get_communication_history&proj_id="+proj_id,
        "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "Search..",
        }       
    });
});

function showMessage() {
    $('table#get_communication_history > tbody').html("");
    parentHtml = $('<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="communication-history-loading" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Please wait! Getting communication history..</div></td></tr>');
    $('table#get_communication_history tbody').html(parentHtml);
}

function hideOverlay() {
    parentHtml = $('<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="communication-history-loading" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Please wait! Getting communication history..</div></td></tr>');
    $('table#get_communication_history > tbody').remove(parentHtml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request will take some time to be processed on server and returned.

You can use some loader to indicate that data is loading:

```
$('a.communication-data[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    // Indicate that you are loading data
    $('#get_communication').html('<tr><td>Loading...</td></tr>');

    // now do Ajax call
}
```

Comment: how to remove the loading content when ajax give response?

Comment: @NewUser It should overwrite current table content.

Comment: Nope its not doing like that. I have tested the code. Even after ajax response its showing the loader row

Comment: Thanks for showing light for this issue. I have got the solution. Check my answer.